# SQL Query Simple Issue subselect

Tags: sql, db2

I have to show the output in 1 row from the country with maximum number of males in the 20-24 range. But sex_ratio should show for all ranges?

```
SELECT age,male ,female,sex_ratio,country                     
FROM census.population                                        
WHERE country<> 'Aggregated' and census.population.age='20-24'
ORDER BY male DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

It should go like this:

```
 --*** select age,                                       ****  
    --***        total number of males,                     ****  
    --***        total number of females,                   ****  
    --***        sex_ratio,(of every age)                   ****  
    --***        country                                    ****  
    --***  where the country has the highest number of      ****  
    --***  males in the 20-24 age range                     ****
```

my output so far:

```
AGE                    MALE                     FEMALE      SEX_RA  COUNTRY   
20-24                 58275712                 51794339      112.5  India
```

The Result should be India because it has the maximum number of males in the 20-24 range  with sex-ratio of every age (not just 20-24). 
census.population.age = 'Total' would deliver sex-ratio of every age. How do i get sex_ratio of total age and the country with most males 20-24 ? What subselect is working for sex_ratio?
My idea was this but it isn't working.

```
SELECT age,male ,female,sex_ratio,country                     
FROM census.population                                        
WHERE country<> 'Aggregated' and census.population.age='20-24'
AND sex_ratio = (select sex_ratio from census.population
WHERE census.population.age = 'Total')
ORDER BY male DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

My Database

```
Column Name        Description
REGION             "WORLD"
COUNTRY            "AGGREGATED" and 228 separate countries
YR                 "2015"
AGE                "Total" and 29 separate age ranges
BOTH_SEXES          AGE range number
MALE                AGE range number
FEMALE              AGE range number
PERCENT_BOTH_SEXES  AGE range percent
PERCENT_MALE        AGE range percent
PERCENT_FEMALE      AGE range percent
SEX_RATIO           AGE range ratio
```

Comment: Can you pls provide a sample expected output? I struggle to understand what you would like to achieve here.

Comment: I updated my post. I know i need a subselect but im stuck.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a bit more clearer now. Yes, you need a subselect, where you get the highest number of males within the 20-24 age group, where country is not aggregate. Then you get the country (or countries in case of a tie), and finally you get the summaries for the given country.

```
select t2.country, sum(t3.male) as totalmales, sum(t3.female) as totalfemales
from (select max(male) as maxmale from table where age='20-24' and country<>'Aggregate') t
inner join table t2 on t.maxmale=t2.male
inner join table t3 on t2.country=t3.country
where t2.age='20-24' and t2.country<>'Aggregate'
group by t2.country
```

As you can see, I did not include the sex_ratio in the above query. The reason is that I do not understand what you want to see there.

Comment: Ever age range has a sex_ratio. Like 0-4 102.9 , 5-9 103.3 and so on. I shall give out the total sex_ratio. Age is then "Total". The Syntax doesn't work on my System(ibm).

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot make any adjustments to my code based on a 'doesn't work' feedback. You need to tell me exactly what the error message was. I still do not understand what you would like to see in the sex_ratio field as an output. Describing the inputs in more detail will not help. Describe the expected output.

Comment: Okay im almost done.
                                                                
 `SELECT age,male ,female,sex_ratio,country                      
 FROM census.population                                         
 WHERE country<> 'Aggregated' and census.population.age='20-24' 
 ORDER BY male DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY; `    

Is giving out 1 row of India which is correct, but my sex_ratio is still for the age 20-24 and it should be for age total. Now this is where i need my Subselect i guess.

Comment: This is not mysql syntax. Are you using db2?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT age, male, female, sex_ratio, country
FROM census.population
WHERE country = (SELECT country 
                 FROM census.population 
                 WHERE male = MAX(male)
                 AND sex_ratio = '20-24');
```

Where you are using a subquery to select the country that has the maximum number of males and the sex ratio is between 20-24. You should not have to order the selection because the return will only be one entry.

or you could try:

```
SELECT age, male, female, sex_ratio, country
FROM census.population
GROUP BY country
HAVING MAX(male) 
AND sex_ratio = '20-24'
ORDER BY male DESC;
```

Using a HAVING clause if you really want to order all of the results, this will return all of the countries in the database.

Comment: Your queries disregard the aggregate records, 2nd query is against sql standards and runs in mysql only under certain settings. No reaction to total male / female, and across al age group sex ratio.

Comment: I have the right select now (in terms of max males in 20-24 and country) but i need a special sex_ratio record of the country from all ages not 20-24.

Comment: So you want to list the max number of males for every age range?